# React i18next useTranslation Hook in helper method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

I'm using React with react-i18next

My index.tsx File contains some components and I can use the Translation function there

**`index.js`**

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as utils from './Utils';
import './i18n';
import { useTranslation, withTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next';

...
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  //I can use the translate function here
  t("title");
  //call a util function
  utils.helperFunction(...);
...
```

Everything works fine here.
I now created some helper functions in an additional file

**`Utils.tsx`**

```js
...
import { useTranslation, withTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next';
...
export function helperFunction(props: any){
   //do stuff

   //now I need some translation here - but useTranslation is not working?
   const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
   t("needTranslation");
}
```

How can I use the same translation logic inside my helper function? (without always passing the `t` function to the helper-method)

Or is the usage of the hook the wrong approach here?

The following error occurs

```
React Hook "useTranslation" is called in function "helperFunction" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed my issue by not using the `useTranslation` hook anymore

Instead I moved the `i18n` initalizitation to a file (i18n.tsx - exports `i18n`)
and import and use it in my Utils class

My **Utils.tsx** file now looks like this

##### **`Utils.tsx`**

```
...
import i18n from '../i18n';
...
export function helperFunction(props: any){
   //do stuff

   //use imported i18n and call the t() method
   i18n.t("needTranslation");
}
```

##### **`i18n.tsx`**

```js
import i18n from "i18next";
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n
  .use(Backend) 
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    lng: "es",
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
    },    
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

  export default i18n;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I want to mention that this doesn't work however when you want to use namespaces. You need to write i18n.t(namespace:needTranslation)

Comment: I simply import like this: `import { useTranslation as translation } from 'react-i18next';`

Answer (score 1):

> Or is the usage of the hook the wrong approach here?

I would say that because useTranslation is a hook and if you try to use it in the helper function, it won't allow you to do so and you'd have to return a react function component or custom React Hook function as the message says

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you forgot a quote `t("needTranslation);` -> `t("needTranslation");`

After I ran your code I see why your code isn't working. If you want to extract component logic into reusable functions, then you should make a custom hook. For more info look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import i18n from "i18next";
import "./i18n.js";
import { useTranslation, initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) 
  .init({
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          title: "Hello world",
          subtitle: "Hello stackoverflow"
        }
      }
    },
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  useHelperFunction();
  return <h1>{t("title")}</h1>;
}

// you need to turn the helper function into a hook
function useHelperFunction() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return <h2>{t("subtitle")}</h2>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: you are right, I simplyfied my example for SO and didn't checked the syntax - but my issue is not syntax related, I updated the code and added the error message

Comment: Thanks for help, but I'm sorry it didn't work for me (same error in my app), but I'm now using `i18n` without the hook and everything works fine (see my answer)