# How to extract useTranslate as a helper function but not a component?

Tags: typescript, next.js, internationalization

I am using Next.js now and I am trying to do translation on those text with ['next-translate/useTranslation'](https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate)

As I may not have all strings in the application translated, and I write a checking function to check if the string is in my translation JSON file (common). If it is, return translated string, else just show the original string

The target is that the translation checking function is extracted as a utility function that can be reused in every page.

Current usage: Copy the function into every component needed translation (repeated code in every component therefore)

```
type Props = {}

const testComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = () => {
  const { t, lang } = useTranslation('common');

  //the checking function used
  const checkStringTranslated = (string2bChecked:string)=>{
    if(t(string2bChecked).includes('common'))return false
    return true
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{checkStringTranslated("String2bTranslated")?t("String2bTranslated"):"String2bTranslated"}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have found a post that achieves that but not in Next.js: [React i18next useTranslation Hook in helper method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394820/react-i18next-usetranslation-hook-in-helper-method)

And I have no clue how to do that in Next.js. How can I make this less redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a helper function for it, `next-translate` provides that functionality through the `default` property in the `options` object when calling the `t` function from `useTranslate`.

```js
const testComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation('common');
  
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{t("String2bTranslated", undefined, { default: "String2bTranslated" })}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank You! I just screened through it quickly before using it. I should have spent more time reading the document.